# file handling in capl programming

Tags: file-handling, capl, canoe

please give me some hint how to perform File handling in CAPL programming.
How to open and how to access the file , what and which types of functions are available for file handling.

give some suggestion regarding this topics.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CAPL syntax provides you with some functions. To open a file stream for reading, use `openFileRead();`.

You may use function `fileGetString()` to read lines from such file. A code snippet might look like

```
char input[30] = "test.txt"
int bufferLength = 256;
char buffer[bufferLength];
dword fh;

fh = openFileRead(input,0);
while(fileGetString(buffer,bufferLength,fh)!=0) {
    // do whatever
}
```

Please put some more effort next time: this is not [how StackOverflow works](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).